# Spring boot jpa tables is not being created SQL SERVER

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

The application is running without errors but the tables are not being created

- i'm using docker, here is my docker file

```yaml
services:
  sqlserver:
    container_name: todo_list_sqlserver

    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

    volumes:
      - sqlserver:/var/opt/mssql

    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "#DevEnv123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"

    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:1430:1433"

    networks:
      - sqlserver

    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  sqlserver:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sqlserver:
```

- i have been configured the application.properties

```
spring.name="Todo List"

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1430;databaseName=todolist
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=#DevEnv123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=3000
```

- the database is created
- and i can connect via beekeeper for example

but when i run the application, the tables are not created

see how my entities look like:

```java
...

@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserPermission> userPermissions;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

```java
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Permission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "permission")
    private Set<UserPermission> userPermissions;
}
```

```java
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class UserPermission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false)
    private Permission permission;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

i'm a backend developer but, not with java i'm so confuse

I need that the tables to be created i have tried so much other things but never works.

i'm using java 17 with maven

Comment: I know the IP listed is a local IP for your database, but please redact/remove passwords entirely

Comment: Hi Marcos, welcome to stack overflow.  How do you expect the database tables to be created for you?  Are you expecting (I assume) hibernate to create them for you?

Comment: Yeah, i expect that. another tests that i have made just works, but now, i don't seeing what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: might it be that, by default, there is already a table called USER ?

Second hunch: there is an issue with the other entity called UserPermission ?

I would definitely check logging, if the tables are not created than there must be an error being logged.

Comment: have no tables on database and no error is shown, it is so confuse. i'm trying to solve a while